# Should I use "will" or "would" here?

Tags: grammar, verbs

> I doubt they **will** exchange the 20 inch monitor.

OR

> I doubt they **would** exchange the 20 inch monitor.

Which is correct, and why?

Comment: Related: [Explanation for usage Would, Would have, Will, Will have](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/3657/).

Comment: Alenanno, if you pay attention, the link you suggested is my older post which doesn't address the issue in this post.

Comment: You're right lol, I didn't notice it was the same author! But well, wasn't that question a general one that covers this one as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are acceptable, but the usage is slightly different. The following extensions to the sentence illustrate the most common usage:

> I doubt they **will** exchange the 20 inch monitor **when** I take it back.
>
> I doubt they **will** exchange the 20 inch monitor **if** I **take** it back (but I may try to).
>
> I doubt they **would** exchange the 20 inch monitor **if** I **took** it back (but I'm not going to).

In general, *would* is used in situations hypothetical, or contingent on some unfulfilled condition; *will* is used in situations that are more certain. The first sentence takes *will* because the speaker definitely intends to take the monitor back. The second uses *will* because, although there is a condition, there is a definite possibility of it being fulfilled. The third sentence takes *would* because the speaker has no intention of taking it back—and therefore the condition is entirely hypothetical.

Comment: What about "I doubt they would exchange the 20 inch monitor if I take it back"? Is it considered acceptable? I know that this sentence, which too has a present-tense verb in the *if*-clause and auxiliary *would* in the consequent clause, **is** considered acceptable: "If you decide to sell the car, we would make an offer".

Comment: Both that and your "car" sentence sound slightly off to me - I'd definitely prefer "If you decideD to sell the car, we would make an offer", or "If you decide to sell the car, we WILL make an offer".

Comment: Hmm, the acceptability judgment varies then. I saw a high-rep contributor (native speaker) here who found the latter sentence so good that he used it to illustrate why the "*if + present-tense, would*" construction is fine in English.

Comment: It probably is an area of variation - certainly modals and conditionals are both areas that show a lot of variation in terms of regional dialect. What variety of English did the other contributor speak? (I'm from the UK!). It's not a huge deal though - I would correct that sentence if I were editing a book for publication, say, but if someone said it in normal speech, or dropped it in an email, I probably wouldn't notice...

Comment: Probably the dialect spoken in Philadelphia, USA, as he has given his location as that in his profile. (Here's the [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/162138/if-would-present-tense#comment324622_162138) I was talking about, btw.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is difficult to distinguish as the context is missing, I mean, what does a monitor has to do with anything mentioned in the previous sentences?

Furthermore, the last sentence is broken, or at least an article is missing there. Either they "will exchange **a** 20-inch monitor", or "they will exchange **the** 20-inch monitor".

Grammatically, both sentences are correct, but depending on the context, which we don't know here, one of them would be more suitable.