# Can "If I would" ever be correct?

Tags: grammaticality, conditionals, would

I came across this construction that was being said by a native English speaker (AmE):

> Usually actually at this point, you don't really know what the Git
>   repository is going to be so I'm not sure **if I would** ever know
>   this question.

Is that a grammatical inaccuracy, or is the "If I would" construction correct in some contexts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I'm not sure if I would ever know this question" is not grammatically correct, but "if I would" is perfectly valid.

**Would** is a [modal auxiliary verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_verb) that indicates the likelihood of something; in this case, whether or not the speaker "knows the question." I'm assuming he is referring to the answer to the question; "I'm not sure if I would ever know the answer to this question" is grammatically correct and suggests that the question may be impossible to answer.

Comment: My non-native knowledge tells me the sentence should read `if I will ever know` am I wrong ?

Comment: @Alex - You aren't necessarily wrong. _Would_ and _will_ are both acceptable in this sentence, and mean [slightly different things](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25906/should-i-use-will-or-would-here). _Will_ suggests that the speak will continue to seek an answer, while _would_ implies that the speaker has given up or lost interest in finding an answer.