# Future Tense - Will vs. Would

Tags: future

I am bit confused for the use of will & would, still not understanding where is it necessary or where we can use one or other.

Following examples for your kind perusal:

A) What will be your answer?     (indicates casual manner)
B) What would be your answer? (indicates formal manner)

I believe both are correct and can be used as per the situation.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide sample sentenced.

Comment: Let Suppose; If someone ask with us about our annual income then

Comment: @UmairKhan: You have a detailed answer here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/when-should-i-use-would-would-have-will-and-will-have