# past vs present

Tags: would

I already told Mark that when he arrived, we would go out for dinner.

Can we say below instead of above?

I already told Mark that when he arrives, we will go out for dinner.

Comment: A useful answer can be found here: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/3664/228732

Answer (score 1):

> I already told Mark that when he arrived, we would go out for dinner.
>
> Can we say below instead of above?
>
> I already told Mark that when he arrives, we will go out for dinner

Below is correct:

If you are using British English, then we would probably use the present perfect:
I've already told Mark that when he arrives (arriving hasn't happened yet, so not past) we will go out for dinner