# How to write an imagined, hypothetical future and consequences?

Tags: grammar, will-would, conditional-future

What is the best way to let a character speak about some hypothetical future and the resulting consequences?

Example:

> If the Martians attacked, I'd fly the jet and you'd be my wing-man.
>   You'd be the best! This will be awesome!

Is this correct in written or spoken form?
The sentences are supposed to mean:
In a future, hypothetical (unlikely) scenario in which Martians attack, the speaking character will fly a jet and the other character will be his wing-man. The other character will be the best wing-man, given the scenario. The scenario of flying a jet with the other person against Martians is seen as awesome by the speaking character. The speaking character does not think Martians exist.

Is it correct to use "It will be awesome" or "It would be awesome"?

What if the scenario is less hypothetical: Martians exist and the character knows about them. The Martians are not planning to attack and their attack is very, very unlikely.
How will this change the sentences?

Comment: Hi Rian, welcome to ELU. I guess you're asking specifically about the grammatical tenses used. [This](https://www.englishpage.com/conditional/futureconditional.html) might help, especially the part about "Future Unreal Conditional".

Comment: Thanks, Pam, cool learning material. I'm still having trouble to formulate the sentences. Most examples cover just one sentence. I'm especially worried about the "This will be awesome" part, which, I guess, is a future real conditional as part of the consequences of a future unreal conditional. i.e. "This will be awesome" is the consequence of flying a jet and not the consequence of "Martians attack".

Comment: Of course you know that the wingman has his own jet and flies in formation with the leader, just off his wing...

Comment: Yes, but I'm still wondering if the grammar is correct.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/when-should-i-use-would-would-have-will-and-will-have
Would vs. will explained.
The word "will" appears to be correct based on the link, considering that you are speaking about a future scenario

Comment: No - that is not in the real future.  Stick with 'would'.