# What the difference between "can" and "would" / "will" and "would"?

Tags: grammar, differences, would

I just came across a paragraph in my English learning text book————

> ①To begin with, Will you please consider installing self-checkout machines, which **would** render readers and librarians more convenience? ②Furthermore, it is expected to adopt online reading room reservation, which **can** reduce reader's waiting time.

I am confused that why uses "would" in the first sentence but not "will" or "can" ?
Similarly I also don't understand why I can't use "would" or "will" in the second one?
(My teacher told me "No", but didn't give me reasons)

Comment: Of possible interest is [When should I use “Would”, “Would have”, “Will”, and “Will have”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/when-should-i-use-would-would-have-will-and-will-have)

Comment: _Render [someone] more convenience_ doesn't seem very idiomatic to me. The _would_ is an implied conditional; 'If you were to install the machines, it would be more convenient for readers'. You can use _will_ in the second sentence, but it would mean that waiting time will certainly be reduced. _Can_ means that the reduction is a possible outcome.

Comment: The "would" is conditional on the installation. It might be better as "which would be more convenient for readers and librarians".